# How does one cshtml call a function in another cshtml?

Tags: function, razor, webmatrix

In webmatrix I have created a DAL.cshtml in App_Data with lots of public static functions.

I want to call them from a different .cshtml page in a different folder.

Presently I get
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name DAL does not exist in the current context

*(note I'm a beginner following a blog about moving the data access to a single location)*

In my DAL.cshtml an example is:

```
public static void AddProfile (dynamic Profile) 
{
var sql = "INSERT INTO profile (ProfileDescription, ProfileType) " +
            "VALUES (@0, @1)";
            PinwheelDB.Execute(sql, Profile.ProfileDescription, Profile.ProfileType);
            var Profile.ProfileID = PinwheelDB.GetLastInsertId();
}
```

In my 'calling' .cshtml I have:

```
        dynamic Profile = new ExpandoObject();
            Profile.ProfileDescription = Request.Form["txtChildFirstName"];
            Profile.ProfileType = 1;
        functions.DAL.AddProfile(Profile);
        var vProfileID = Profile.ProfileID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I moved the DAL.cshtml into a folder called App_Code instead of App_Data (Thank-you Darin) it just worked.

Please note that the code I have ended up with is as follows (in case it helps another beginner)........

DAL.cshtml now in a folder called App_Code I have:

```
@functions 
{
public static void AddProfile (dynamic Profile) 
{
var sql = "......"                
PinwheelDB.Execute(sql, .......);
}
```

The calling .cshtml
remains as I first quoted

If anyone knows why this is I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could put commonly used methods in classes in the `App_Code` folder. For example you could have a `~/App_Code/DAL.cs`:

```
public class DAL
{
    public static void AddProfile(dynamic profile)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and in your calling Razor page:

```
@{
    var profile = ...
    DAL.AddProfile(profile);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I have missed some details on my code excerpts in the original question....I think I already have it as you have described. The calling Razor bit is contained in @{}. I have ~/App_Code/DAL.cshtml.       However the calling razor page has no reference to the ~/App_Code/DAL.cs could that be the problem?   thx

Comment: @CharlotteCopper, no, you have put it in the `App_Data` folder which is not the same as `App_Code`. Also you used `DAL.cshtml` whereas I used `DAL.cs` which once again is not the same thing at all.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll try to copy . There doesn't seem to be a file extension .cs available when I create a new webmatrix page. thank-you

Comment: @CharlotteCopper, it's C#. I think you should really read a little about it before jumping into Razor.

Comment: I am trying to follow the blog/tutorial here that says it is possible: http://blog.stevelydford.com/2011/05/creating-a-data-access-layer-using-dynamics-in-webmatrix/